# Getting the database ID of the current row via load event

Tags: javascript, jquery

i used this code for click event but how to get when the form load get the TR values

my code

```
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable();
    $('#mytable tbody').on('click','#btnview',function () {
        var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
       alert(data[0]);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

After `binding` the `click event` you can `trigger` the `click event` of btn

```
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable();
    $('#mytable tbody').on('click','#btnview',function () {
        var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
       GetRowData(data);
    });

//trigger the click event 

$('#btnview').trigger('click');

function GetRowData(data)
{
 alert(data[0]);
}
```

Now when you will click button this function will be called and you can get the data.

Comment: You can make a `function`  which you can call on click of button and pass row data.

Comment: kindly... can you please give for example for this